# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function $

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using a asp.net site.
I'm including this script in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#settings, #agency_text').on('click', function () {
            $('#logout').fadeToggle('fast');
        });
  </script>
```

then I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that the jQuery library wasn't loaded (correctly).
First you need to load in the jQuery library to be able to perform jQuery functions.

Add this line above your script in html

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

For more info check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) page here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: I'm using "jquery-1.4.1.min.js" in the project, I still get same error

Comment: `on` was added in jQuery 1.7. **Don't use** jQuery 1.4.1 - it is ancient. You should also have included that information in the question.

Comment: Is the website using another version of jQuery for something else?

Comment: I use a new version of jquery, it works thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

add $(document).ready(function(){ });

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){      
    $('#settings, #agency_text').on('click', function () {
        $('#logout').fadeToggle('fast');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: did you add the jquery script ??

Comment: Yes I'm using "jquery-1.4.1.min.js"

Answer (score -1):

I also change my code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#settings, #agency').click(function () {
                $('#logout').slideToggle('fast');
            });
        });
</script>
```

It works with "jquery-1.4.1.min.js" :)