# Javascript functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to jQuery so am just trying out some basic commands. However nothing I try is working. For example I'm trying to hide an element. 
I have a folder (js) containing a JavaScript file main.js so I'm pretty sure my file structure is correct

```html
<head>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>        
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
      <div id="audio-buttons">
            <button id="prev"></button>
            <button id="play"></button>
            <button id="pause"></button>
            <button id="stop"></button>
            <button id="next"></button>
        </div>

</body>
```

In my main.js file I have the following

```
var audio;

$('#pause').hide();
```

Comment: add the part of html to the question where you are including the javascript file and the function you are expecting to execute.

Comment: Give more details...

Comment: From what I see you html file is only </body> which is definitely not complete. Please post full code

Comment: your code works. are u sure JS is included properly?

Comment: `var audio` just declares a variable and never uses it. `$('#pause').hide()` just hides the pause button.

Comment: add $(document).ready(function(){...} around the code?

Comment: If you want the `$('#pause').hide();` to execute right when the file loads, try `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#pause').hide(); });`

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi with that ordering the JS code wont work for  at least 2 reasons.

Comment: @sirko haha, that was a test for being attentive

Comment: You failed to mention the error message you are receiving.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429473/

Answer (score 3):

change from this:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>        
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
      <div id="audio-buttons">
            <button id="prev"></button>
            <button id="play"></button>
            <button id="pause"></button>
            <button id="stop"></button>
            <button id="next"></button>
        </div>

</body>
```

to this:

```
<head>      
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="js/main.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
      <div id="audio-buttons">
            <button id="prev"></button>
            <button id="play"></button>
            <button id="pause"></button>
            <button id="stop"></button>
            <button id="next"></button>
        </div>

</body>
```

and use inside main.js :

```
var audio;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pause').hide();
});
```

or

```
var audio;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#pause').hide();
});
```

updated answer as there are missing `)` at the end
and learn more about jquery on their own site:

https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: lol why down voted ?

Comment: lol again ? why down voted ?

Answer (score 1):

You must call your jquery function after you load jquery.
You should put it either in an event handler, or in the .ready function.

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $().ready(function() {
      $('#pause').hide();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="audio-buttons">
    <button id="prev">Prev</button>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <button id="pause">Pause</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load jQuery before using it:

```
<head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>        
</head>
```

Function needs to be called after the document is loaded:

```
var audio;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pause').hide();
}
```

Comment: you must also load jquery before you run any jquery code.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: it was downvoted because of my comment, after which you edited your answer. I'm removing the downvote because you corrected your answer.

Comment: Maybe because the question should be closed rather than answered 5+ times. It's both a duplicate and off topic for not providing the error message received. (even though we all know what that error message states)

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of your `<script>` tags.  `main.js` should be loaded *after* `jQuery` is loaded, or else it won't work.

Comment: you must also wait for the document to load before calling the function.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to add that in and saw a ton of folks w/ more complete answers already.

Comment: Thank you for the help gentlemen . the issue is resolved and has helped my understanding

Answer (score 0):

Your JS file is loaded and executed as soon as it is ready, which means it might run before your DOM is ready.

To fix this you have a couple of choices.
First, you can wrap everything in a "ready" function, like Aragorn suggested in his answer, or you can delay the loading of your file (recommended in this case).

So, try moving `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` after `</body>` and run your code again.

There is another thing: some componentes of jQUery are sensitive to order. That being said, you should always load jQuery first, and then use it, and not the other way around. This might very well be the cause of your problem because the browser might be trying to run `$('#pause').hide();` before `$` is even defined by jQuery.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the downvote? It took you LITERALLY half a second to downvote my answer, and it is precise.

Comment: I upvoted you, your answer was good, and instead of just providing corrected code you also gave an explanation. It appears that someone downvoted all answers other than their own.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to check if page is already full loaded:

```
var audio;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pause').hide();
});
```

Please consider to change loading sort:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Happy to help you!